# Переписать компонет на Hooks

Tags: reactjs, классы, компоненты, react-hook

я новенький в React, изучаю React hooks. Подскажите как переписать state части классового компонента на хуки. Данные elements приходят из json файла. У меня чёт никак не выходит.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { elements } from './_data';
import Element from './Element';

class App extends Component {
 state = {
  showInfo: false,
  element: {}
};

showInfo = (num) => {
  this.setState({ showInfo: true, element: elements[num] });
};

closeInfo = () => {
  this.setState({ showInfo: false });
};

render() {
  let { name, summary, symbol, category, number, 
    source, appearance, atomic_mass, molar_heat, 
    density, melt, boil } = this.state.element;
// ...
```